# Isotropy of the Minkowski metric

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

An [isotropic tensor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsotropicTensor.html) has the same components in all rotated coordinate systems.

Scalars or tensors of rank zero are isotropic. Tensors of rank one or vectors are not isotropic. The only isotropic rank-2 tensor is the Kronecker delta.

How could one show or prove that the Minkowski metric $\eta_{ab}$ is not isotropic?

Could it be shown that the roatational invariance

$\eta_{ij}= R_{im} R_{jn} \eta_{mn}= \eta'_{ij}$

does not hold for the Minkowski metric?

Comment: I don't understand this topic well. If the only rank-2 isotropic tensor is the Kronecker delta or a multiple of the Kronecker delta, how can the Minkowski metric be isotropic?

Comment: I saw this question a couple of days ago in an online chat room about physics. I did some research about this subject, then I asked the question here. I have some knowledge about tensors but regretfully it's limited.

Comment: I see, sorry if my tone came off as hostile. It smelled like homework.

Answer (score 1):

The usages of "isotropic" and "rotational invariance" here are not at all standard as applied to a semi-Riemannian space. According to normal usage, the Minkowski metric is isotropic rotationally invariant (as are, e.g., FLRW spacetimes).

> If the only rank-2 isotropic tensor is the Kronecker delta or a multiple of the Kronecker delta, how can the Minkowski metric be isotropic?

Your statement is not true according to standard usage in a semi-Riemannian space. The wolfram.com page that you linked to, which makes this statement, is not about semi-Riemannian spaces, it's about Riemannian spaces.

Spacetime is semi-Riemannian: it has 3 spatial dimensions and 1 time dimension. The term "rotation" is used only for rotations in the 3 spatial dimensions. The Minkowski metric is invariant under those 3-dimensional rotations.

Comment: I guess I should read more about semi-Riemannian spaces. I appreciate the clarifications.